# Understanding the writer type

Tags: haskell, syntax, functional-programming, monads, record

I am learning about monads in the book 'Learn You a Haskell for Great Good!' by Miran Lipovaca. I am reading about how the Control.Monad.Writer module exports the `Writer w a` type along with its Monad instance and some useful functions for dealing with values of this type.

For the following code:

```
newtype Writer w a = Writer { runWriter :: (a,w) }
```

I know that the `a` type parameter represents the type of some value, and the `w` type parameter represents the type of the attached monoid value. Am I correct in saying that by passing `w` and `a` to the `Writer` type constructor, you get a Writer monad in return, with this monad only having one function which is the `runWriter` function?

In the book it says that the `runWriter` function takes a tuple that's wrapped in a `Writer` newtype and unwraps it, returning a simple tuple. However the type declaration of `runWriter` is `runWriter :: (a,w)`, it doesn't take any parameters as input. How does `runWriter` take a tuple that's wrapped in a newtype and return just a simple tuple?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Am I correct in saying that by passing `w` and `a` to the Writer type constructor, you get a Writer monad in return,

No, `Writer w` is the monad (assuming `Monoid w`). `Writer w a` is a type.

> with this monad only having one function which is the `runWriter` function?

No, the type `Writer w a` is, essentially, a pair type `(a,w)`. There are no functions inside.

You can pretend that the type is defined in the following way

```
newtype Writer w a = Writer (a,w)
```

and that there is a separate convenience "unwrapping" function

```
runWriter :: Writer w a -> (a,w)
runWriter (Writer p) = p
```

You can think of these functions as being mutual inverses:

```
Writer :: (a,w) -> Writer w a        -- "wrapper"
runWriter :: Writer w a -> (a,w)     -- "unwrapper"
```

Using the *record syntax* in `data` declarations indeed defines functions taking an implicit argument (in addition to the data type itself).
Any type

```
data T = MkT { f :: Int, g :: String }
```

defines the data type `T`, data constructor `MkT`, and functions `f`, `g` having an implicit `T` argument,

```
f :: T -> Int               -- f (MkT i _) = i
g :: T -> String            -- g (MkT _ s) = s
```

Record syntax with `newtype`s works in the same way, except that there must be exactly *one* field (named `runWriter`, in your example).

Comment: For your example, runWriter (Writer p) = p, am I correct in saying that Writer p is a monad? So essentially runWriter (Writer p) = p will take out whatever is inside the monad? Also how can you tell that Writer w a is a pair type? Any insights are appreciated.

Comment: @ceno980 `Writer p` is a value, so it can not be a monad, which is a type-level thing. We might say that `Writer p` is a "monadic value", i.e. a value of type `m a` for some monad `m` and type `a`. It is correct that `runWriter` extracts what's under the `Writer` wrapper. `Writer w a` is essentially a pair since it is defined in that way: if we put `newtype T = T { runT :: A }` then types `T` and `A` are essentially the same -- they differ only by their names. You can convert `x :: A` into `T x :: T`, and back `y :: T` into `runT y :: A` without losing information.

Comment: if you write it as `newtype Writer w a = MkWriter (a,w)` there's no confusing the data (`MkWriter p`) with the type (`Writer w a`). @ceno980

Comment: @chi For this line: data T = MkT { f :: Int, g :: String }. Basically, the data type T has a value constructor MkT with two fields f and g which are of types Int and String respectively. And in order to create a field with value Int/String you have to pass the data type itself (T) to the functions f/g to get the value? Is this correct?

Comment: @ceno980 not quite. we can construct `T` values like `x = MkT 1 "a"`; and we can handle those values with `f x == 1` and `g x == "b"`. *But*, we can also use the *record syntax* to create the values, like `x = MkT { g="a", f=1 }`. then there's the record *update* syntax `y = x {f=2}`.

Comment: I know that f returns an Int and g returns a String but how did you get the values 1 and "b" specifically in the example: f x == 1 and g x == "b".

Comment: @ceno980 They should have been `f x == 1` and `g x == "a"`, taken from the arguments of `MkT` in `x = MkT 1 "a"`. Essentially, `f` here takes the first argument, and `g` the second one.

Comment: `g x == "b"` was intended to return `False`.

Comment: @WillNess I see, but it wasn't that obvious :-)

Comment: yeah, perhaps I made it more confusing than need be.